# How to dynamically fetch data from mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

**I'm looking to get the values dynamically from the database using NodeJS**
What i am doing now is that i am taking the values hard-coded.

> **Note**:
>   **$text** : The collection index.

```
 db.collection('Questions').find({$text: {$search: typed}}, {projection: { _id: 0, "How": 1, "Where": 1, "Who Approves": 1, "Applied Extra": 1, "Inform Personally": 1, "Pre Planning": 1, "Types": 1}}).toArray(function(err, result) {
        if (err)
            console.log(err);

        if (typed.trim() == "How To Apply") {
            var responding_how = JSON.stringify(result).substring(JSON.stringify(result).indexOf("How") + 6, JSON.stringify(result).indexOf("You Want Off On.") + 15)
            console.log("How To Apply - " + responding_how);
            res.send(responding_how);
        }
        if (typed.trim() == "Where To Apply") {
            var responding_where = JSON.stringify(result).substring(JSON.stringify(result).indexOf("https://"), JSON.stringify(result).indexOf("Who Approves") - 3)
            console.log("Where To Apply - " + responding_where);
            res.send("<a target='_blank' href=" + responding_where + ">Apply off</a>");
        }
```

Comment: In mongo, There is no specific column and specific row.

Comment: yeah its nosql and hold no specific things but how can i operate the needed operation as i told above.

Answer (score 0):

Make a new collection , make it hold all your "headers" , you can call it Projections.
Query that collection (find({})).
Send the quert response (after exception-check) to the Questions "find" query :

```
db.collection('Questions').find({$text: {$search: typed}},ProjectionsResponse 
}).toArray(...
...)
```

**I hope this is what you meant..**

Comment: I dont understand the difference in projection and the ProjectionsResponse. Without it everything appear same to me

Comment: it's the response you get from the query  , a cleaner way to put understandable code nothing more.

Comment: how is that @AayushiGupta ?

Comment: My problem is how i can remove hardcoded if else adn response over it which i have taken as indexAt thing.